# Strings to add when I push objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, object

I need to add two strings in an js file I am generating with `writeFileSync`

This is the code example

```
const svgs = [];
var n = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  svgs.push(Cog.prototype.render());
  svgs.push(Manna.prototype.render());
}

fs.writeFileSync(`client/data/${name}.json`, JSON.stringify(svgs));
```

And this is the js file I am generating ( two objects in an array )

```
[{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/svg/2000","viewBox":{"viewBox":"0 0 64 64"},"width":{"size":64},"height":{"size":64},"fill":{"fill":"currentcolor"},"path":{"d":{"pathData":"M 2 2 L 62 2 L 62 62 L 2 62 L 2 2"}}},{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/svg/2000","viewBox":{"viewBox":"0 0 64 64"},"width":{"size":64},"height":{"size":64},"fill":{"fill":"currentcolor"},"path":{"d":{"pathData":"M 2 2 L 62 2 L 62 62 L 2 62 L 2 2"}}}]
```

My question is how can I add two strings, this one at the beginning `const svgs =`  and `export default svgs` at the end in order to make my file generated looking like this

```
const svgs = [{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/svg/2000","viewBox":{"viewBox":"0 0 64 64"},"width":{"size":64},"height":{"size":64},"fill":{"fill":"currentcolor"},"path":{"d":{"pathData":"M 2 2 L 62 2 L 62 62 L 2 62 L 2 2"}}},{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/svg/2000","viewBox":{"viewBox":"0 0 64 64"},"width":{"size":64},"height":{"size":64},"fill":{"fill":"currentcolor"},"path":{"d":{"pathData":"M 2 2 L 62 2 L 62 62 L 2 62 L 2 2"}}}] export default svgs;
```

Comment: `fs.writeFileSync(`client/data/${name}.json`, "const svgs =" + JSON.stringify(svgs)) + "export default svgs" ;`

Comment: add as answer , this is slightly corrected  "const svgs =" + JSON.stringify(svgs).toString() + "; export default svgs" + ";");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fs.writeFileSync(client/data/${name}.json, "const svgs =" + JSON.stringify(svgs)) + "export default svgs" ;
```